# Simulate browser and control programmatically

Tags: python, google-chrome, firefox, selenium, flash

I am trying to run a headless browser, to which when I pass a URL simulates the entire webpage as it would if run from any of the popular browser. Importantly it must manage to run Adobe Flash Player (and hence flash videos). I have heard things about selenium webkit but I am not sure about its capabilities as I have never used it especially when it comes to handling flash content. 
Infact if I were to narrow down the problem, I just want to run a flash content in a web site but out of the internet browsing window under my program (preferably python). If this is possible can someone point me the right approach. Do let me know if any further clarification is needed in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Give a try to http://phantomjs.org/ it works great with a headless webkit and flash.
You could look at http://jeanphix.me/Ghost.py/ to control phantomjs with Python.

Comment: I have worked with Ghost.py especially for loading javascript contents. I am not sure about its flash capabilities ?

Comment: You can enable flash with phantomjs see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtwebkit.html#netscape-plugin-support

Comment: Thanks will give it a try. Will share my experience in a day or two.

Comment: And, so, what about your experience ?